# How to use Element.style.styleFloat?

Tags: javascript, dom, css-float

One of lines below doesn't work:

```
document.getElementById("attribute").setAttribute("style", "float: right");
document.getElementById("field").style.styleFloat = "right";
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/2kvEA/

What's wrong? How setAttribute() can be avoided?

Comment: Isnt it `Element.style.float = "xxx"`

Comment: @dandavis, post your answer, please

Comment: You will find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606470/is-there-a-cross-browser-way-of-setting-style-float-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use the dom property element.style.cssFloat to adjust CSS's float property to avoid the use of the JS reserved word "float".